# Structured code for limiting what values you can set for a property

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

What would be the correct (and best) way to code in limits as to what values a property can get?

For example, suppose I have the following simple class:

```
Public Class MyClass
   Public Property MyDate As Date
```

Now, suppose `MyDate` gets set at run-time, but can't take any values less than a year ago.

Is it correct to throw an exception in the MyDate's setter and then program this in my main module in a `Try...Catch` fashion and then alert the user if the value is bad or is there a better way to do this?

I'm sure this is a stupidly simple question, but I just want to make sure I'm doing this according to best programming practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, throwing and exception is a good idea. [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx) seems to be the best in that situation. Following the MSDN:

> The exception that is thrown when the value of an argument is outside
>   the allowable range of values as defined by the invoked method.

Answer (score 2):

While throwing an exception is a valid option, I recommend against it. The reason is that when a programmer sets a property he/she expects very little to happen other than the value being set. In this case I'd recommend using a set function instead of a property or having the value passed as part of the constructor (where programmers expect validation logic of this sort to happen).

Comment: @ytoledano - I meant to put the exception in a set function - Based upon all I'm reading here, it seems like that is the correct way to do this - you agree???

Comment: No, I still think that if you might throw an exception while setting you should be exposing a set function and not a property. To clarify, the function should be something like:
void setMyDate(DateTime date){...}
Forgive my c#.
Not having a design warning be displayed doesn't guarantee that you have a good design.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article out.  It gives an overview of Validators in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace.  They are attributes for your model that support validation.

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/09/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-43-use-data-annotation-validators.aspx

ASP.NET MVC supports surfacing those validations on forms using JS, but in other applications types you can read the attributes from the model itself and enforce the validations.